# AutoMapping a Composite Element in Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to get the AutoPersistence model to map several composite elements.  However, it seems that either I end up mapping it as an entity, dropping down to manual mapping or it just doesn't plain work.  Here's some code that demonstrates my problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using FluentNHibernate.AutoMap;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers;
using NHibernate.Cfg;

namespace Scanner {
    public class Root {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Component> Components { get; set; }
    }

    public class Component {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Example {
        public void DoesntGetComponents()
        {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.SetProperty("ConnectionString", "");
            configuration.SetProperty("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect");
            var config = Fluently.Configure(configuration)
                .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMapping))
                .BuildConfiguration();
            var sql2005 = new NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect();
            foreach (var line in config.GenerateSchemaCreationScript(sql2005))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }

        static AutoPersistenceModel AutoMapping() {
            AutoPersistenceModel model = new AutoPersistenceModel();
            return model
                .AddEntityAssembly(typeof(Root).Assembly)
                .WithSetup(e => e.IsComponentType = t => t == typeof(Component))
                .Where(t => t == typeof(Root))
                .MergeWithAutoMapsFromAssemblyOf<Root>()
                .ConventionDiscovery.Add(ForeignKey.Format((p, t) => (p == null ? t.Name : p.Name) + "Id"))
                .ConventionDiscovery.Add(Table.Is(t => t.EntityType.Name))
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

(Sorry it's so long, but it's the minimal code required to demonstrate the problem.  This particular version of the code fails to register the component type at all.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd like to be able to close this question on the basis that it was no longer relevant.  I'm not convinced any new work would use FNH now that NH has similar features.

Comment: Current version of NH (3.2 as I write this) still does not do Automapping a la FNH, which is a good reason to continue with FNH, IMO.

Comment: Point taken.  I'm somewhat of the view that most auto-mapping is actually more easily implemented yourself than trying to get someone else's system working.  I gave up on FNH auto-mapping a long time before I ditched FNH.

Comment: Hmmm...my experience has been the complete opposite.  FNH Automapping has worked very well on my greenfield project, with a reasonably complicated object model.  Also, I see a lot of SO questions on both FNH and NH "mapping by code", for situations that I know Automapping would handle effortlessly.  What kind of problems did you run into?

Comment: I suspect the answer is that I wasn't working on anything remotely resembling greenfield.  ID conventions, exception handling and so forth were all significantly more painful than writing supporting functions that followed the conventions of the code and just not calling them when they didn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the component in itself is not the problem, but the mapping of a collection of components. If you would map the component directly onto the Root class, this would not be any problem.

A possible workaround is making the Component class an entity (adding an ID) and overriding the mapping of Components to cascade + auto delete orphans:

```
AutoPersistenceModel
.ForTypesThatDeriveFrom<Root>(map => map.HasMany(root => root.Components).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan())
```